# Salesforce Lightning Design System Modals

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, slds

I was wondering if anyone had a small example of any of the modal windows working [SLDS Modals](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals). The first example is what I am attempting to replicate. I have all of the SLDS resources loading as static resources and have even inspected the `.css` to ensure the `.slds-modal css` is there.

I couldn't get them to work, so I am temporarily(hopefully) using bootstrap and jQuery to get my error modals up and running for some `VF/Lex` pages.

I have put the code straight into a [codepen](http://codepen.io/VanGrack/pen/YwOXvm) and it doesn't look right there either.

I am new to `SLDS` as well as using modals at all. This is what I am currently getting, and yes the html is properly formed from inspecting the elements in the DOM.

[image: modal errors]

An image of the markup to show it matches the example:

[image: html markup image]

Any help or an example of something working would be great. Thanks.

Comment: It does not look like you have the SLDS resource loaded. What you show in the picture is what it looks like if the SLDS resources did not load or you forgot to include them

Answer (score 1):

Add `<apex:slds />` to your page and wrap your code in a container

```
<div class="slds-scope">...</div>
```

Sample code can be:

```
<apex:page>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            <!-- Import the Design System style sheet -->
            <apex:slds />
       </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slds-scope">...</div>
    </body>
   </html>
</apex:page>
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

The LDS modals given are just the css styling , there is no js or jquery given by the LDS. So you would have to write explicit jquery to show and hide the modal.
It is just the CSS of the modal given by the LDS.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code , call the Javascript method `openDeleteConfirm` to open the dialogue box and call this method `closeWindow()` to close the dialogue window.

```
<apex:page id="idMyPage" standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"  >
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
            <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS092, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />

        </head>
        <apex:form id="idForm" styleClass="slds">
            <div aria-hidden="false" role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-close" id="idDialog">
                <div class="slds-modal__container" style="width:25%">
                    <div class="slds-modal__content">
                        <div>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--align-spread" >
                                Are you sure to delete this record?
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <div class="slds-button-group slds-float--right" role="group">
                            <input type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral cancel" onclick="closeWindow();" value="Cancel" />
                            <input type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--brand save" onclick="deleteRelatedListRecord();" value="Confirm"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal-backdrop slds-modal-backdrop--close"  id="idBackDrop"></div>
        </apex:form>
        <script>
            function openDeleteConfirm()
            {
                    document.getElementById("idDialog").className = document.getElementById("idDialog").className.replace( /(?:^|\s)slds-fade-in-close(?!\S)/g , ' slds-fade-in-open');
                    document.getElementById("idBackDrop").className = document.getElementById("idBackDrop").className.replace( /(?:^|\s)slds-modal-backdrop--close(?!\S)/g , ' slds-modal-backdrop--open');
            }

            function closeWindow()
            {
                    document.getElementById("idDialog").className = document.getElementById("idDialog").className.replace( /(?:^|\s)slds-fade-in-open(?!\S)/g , ' slds-fade-in-close');
                    document.getElementById("idBackDrop").className = document.getElementById("idBackDrop").className.replace( /(?:^|\s)slds-modal-backdrop--open(?!\S)/g , ' slds-modal-backdrop--close');
            }

       </script>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```